# SSLCOMMERZ working on debug apk but not on release apk

Tags: android, flutter, apk, payment-gateway, release

I recently integrated SSLCOMMERS from pubdev into my flutter app. Now that is working fine in debug mode but doesn't work when I create an apk. I've even run the app in release and profile mode but both work fine. I tried adding internet permission which too didn't work. Actually the biggest problem is that i can't see the logs for the apk that I create. Any kind of help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

it's simple.

Use this package: [flutter_sslcommerz](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sslcommerz)

Try these steps

Edit your android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" <!-- add this line must -->
    package="com.itmedicus.congressia.congressia">
```

then

```
   <application
        android:label="congressia"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" <!-- add this line -->
       tools:replace="android:label".  <!-- add this line -->
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

then edit android/app/build.gradle and add these two line in your build types

```
   buildTypes {
        release {
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            shrinkResources false  // add this line
            minifyEnabled false  //add this line
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding this below code to your app's build gradle. After modifying the app's build gradle, please clean the app by the command `flutter clean`, then build the release apk again. Hopefully the issue will be solved.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        // .................. your existing codes ..................
        // add these three lines
        
        shrinkResources false
        zipAlignEnabled false
        minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
```